# Need help creating a square matrix where the number of columns/rows is defined by the user

Tags: ruby, matrix

First of all, I'm a ruby newbie, so I ask that you have patience with me. :) 
Second of all, before you read the request and think I'm trying to get easy answers, trust me, I've spent the last 7 days searching for them online, but haven't found any that answered my very specific question. And third, sorry about the long description, but the help I need is to be pointed in the right direction.

I had an idea for a small class project about genetic drift. In population genetics, a probability matrix is used to give the probability that the frequency of an allele will change from i to j in generation t1 to generation t2.

So, say I start with one copy of allele B in t1 and want to know the probability of it going to three copies in t2. The value (as given by the binomial distribution, to which I have already wrote a small code, which works nicely) then would go in the cell corresponding to column 1, row 3 (perhaps this can clarify things better: https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsamples.jbpub.com%2F9780763757373%2F57373_CH04_FINAL.pdf).

What I don't know how to do and would like to get information on is:

- how do I make a square matrix where the number of rows/columns is determined by the user (say someone wants to get the probability matrix for a population of 4, which has 8 allele copies, but someone else wants to get the probability matrix for a population of 100, which has 200 allele copies?)
- how do I apply the binomial distribution equation to the values of each one of the different column/row combinations (i.e. in the cell corresponding to column 1, row 3, the value would be determined by the binomial equation with variables 1 and 3; and in the cell corresponding to column 4, row 7, the value would be determined by the binomial equation with variables 4 and 7). The number of different combinations of variables (like 1 and 1, 1 and 2, 1 and 3, etc) is determined by the number of columns/rows set by the user.

I'm not asking anyone to give me the code or do my work for me, what I'm asking is for you, seasoned programmers, to point me in the direction of the correct answers, since I've so miserably failed in finding this direction. Should I be looking into arrays instead of matrices? Should I be looking into specific iterators? Which? Does anyone have more specific material I could look into, or could give me tips based on experience with creating matrices? I really want to learn ruby, and learn how to do this, not just get it done.

Comment: This is a bit big to try and answer in one go. Consider breaking it down into smaller questions (there are no penalties on SO for asking lots of questions). Most programming problems become easier if you  break them down into steps in any case.

Comment: Sure the problem really boils down to those two questions, which I could've broken down into two different topics, but I believe that in this case I had to give people a general and detailed view of what I want so they would be able to give me more specific answers.
But thanks for the tip, I'll do it next time.

Comment: So Kimura figured out your second bullet point over 50 years ago.  Take a look at how he used the Diffusion Approximation to work with allele frequencies over time.  Try Gillespie's classic book, Population Genetics: A Concise Guide, or at Ewens's Mathematical Population Genetics.

Comment: I believe you have misunderstood me, I know how to do it myself, I don't know how to make a ruby program do it.

Answer (score 0):

For generating a matrix, you might wish to take a look at the Matrix class: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html which has a method `Matrix.build(row_size, column_size)` looking like a good fit to your problem. It even takes a block that you can use to generate values:

```
require 'matrix'

Matrix.build( 5, 5 ) do |row, col| 
  binomial_function( row, col )
end
```

Obviously you will need to write the binomial function too - seems like you may have done that already?

How to make the rows/columns a user choice, depends on how you want end users to run your code. You should probably make that clear in another question, there some differences in approach between a web site and a command line script.

Comment: Thanks! I did take a look at that ruby-doc site before, but I had no idea which function to even look for! Thanks for pointing it out for me. I already worte the binomial, which works very nicely.